# [React]How to convert props to String?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, jsx

I would like to make a URL link, but all the time I try to make it, it shows `[object]`. How can i convert `{trcode}` to string?

**Code:**

```
function L_MovieList({title, poster, genres, synopsis,language,runtime,year,rating,likes,trcode}) {

    console.log(likes);
    console.log("here"+trcode)

    let url = JSON.stringify({trcode});
    let url_path = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+{url};

    return (
        <div className="L_MovieList">
          <a href={url_path}>예고편</a>   
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Isn't `JSON.stringify()` working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if `trcode` starts as an `[object]`, it will always display as an `[object]` in the `console.log("here"+trcode)` statement above.  Because you're not stringifying the `[object]` until *after* you have done the `console.log()`.

Second, I doubt that `JSON.stringify()` is going to do what you want it to do.  You see, an `[object]` is, in its simplest form, a collection of key-value pairs.  When you stringify an `[object]`, it creates a string representation *of the entire object* - including the keys and the values.  In other words, if this is your `trcode` object:

```
{
    "code" : "lB7p5xeiYpE"
}
```

Then the value you get back from `JSON.stringify(trcode)` will be a string that looks like this:

`{"code":"lB7p5xeiYpE"}`

If you want *the value inside that object*, you're best off using dot notation to get that value directly.  So you would have a line of code that looks something like this:

`let url_path = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+trcode.code;`

Finally, this line of code:

`let url_path = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+{url};`

Will **always** "break" and show an `[object]` being appended to the end of the string, because you're *creating an object on the fly* and then concatenating it onto the end of the string.

The problem happens because of the curly braces that you're wrapping around `url`.  What that's doing is creating a brand new object with `url` as its contents.  In the code above, `url` should already be a string.  This is how you concatenate two strings (notice the **lack** of curly braces):

`let url_path = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+url;`

Answer (score 0):

I think the function definition is not correct it should be something like below.

```
function L_MovieList(argListObject) {
    let url = argListObject.trcode;
    let url_path = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+url;

    return (
        <div className="L_MovieList">
          <a href={url_path}>예고편</a>   
        </div>
    )
}
```

and finally calling your function as

```
L_MovieList({title, poster, genres, synopsis,language,runtime,year,rating,likes,trcode});
```